# Adding tabular report to dashboard

Tags: reporting

As far as I understand from the research I have done on this all morning, it is not possible to put a tabular report on a dashboard that has a bit more detail than specified here: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003933

I need to add a report to a dashboard that contains:

itemRef / date  /  address

This does not seem too complicated, but I am not sure how to solve this problem.
Tia.

Comment: Do you really need `address` visible on a Dashboard? That seems like a lot of detail to have visible on a Dashboard.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have now changed it to not show address.